# Can you combine a function and a condition with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Can you combine a function and a condition on a ng-class, as the following

```
 ng-class="activo(h_m),{ \'hora-select\': h_m.selected,\'hora-select:hover\': h_m.selected}
```

**UPDATE:**

My solution was to just change change `,` by `;` thus being

```
 ng-class="activo(h_m);{ \'hora-select\': h_m.selected,\'hora-select:hover\': h_m.selected}
```

Comment: @Adjit thanks, just that I need to know

Comment: Why not update your value in the controller and use it in ngClass?

Comment: I do not understand what you say  @Isherwood

Comment: I'm playing with this code, but it has to last that will be respected, the others deleted http://embed.plnkr.co/OLaYke/